# Starting multiple instances of Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-11

I just discovered after a very frustrating few hours with frozen Excel sheets that it opens only one instance for multiple files by default. This is apparently handy when Excel needs to be aware of other opened spreadsheets. However, this is not useful when one of these sheets is very large as it slows down the second spreadsheet as well.

There seemed to be a way to open multiple instances of Excel on Windows 8 by keeping the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button pressed while clicking on the Excel icon: [Microsoft 365 blog](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/06/03/opening-workbooks-by-running-separate-instances-of-excel/)

However, this procedure does not seem to work on Windows 11. Any other suggestions other than opening Excel from the terminal with the /X option?

Two Excel spreadsheets in one instance:
[image]

Two Excel spreadsheets in two instances:
[image]

Comment: How do you define "one instance"? Please edit your question to show screenshots of task manager when you have several workbooks open. If you right-click the icon on the taskbar or start menu, you should be able to just select 'Excel' to get another window.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I added the screenshots, I hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Windows 11. I tested the method recommended here and it worked for me:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance

> 1. Exit all instances of Excel.
> 2. Start Registry Editor:
>
> - In Windows 10, click Start, type regedit in the Search box, and then
>   select regedit.exe in the search results.
> - In Windows 8 or Windows 8.1,
>   move the pointer to the upper-right corner, select Search, enter
>   regedit in the search box, and then select regedit.exe in the search
>   results.
>   Locate and select the following registry subkey:
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options`
>
> 3. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then select DWORD Value.
> 4. Enter DisableMergeInstance, and then press Enter.
> 5. In the Details pane, right-click DisableMergeInstance, and then select
>    Modify.
> 6. In Value data, enter 1, and then click OK.

Comment: Thanks, that would work for sure, but for every single time Excel is opened, which might not be ideal. I was looking for a way to open a new instance only for large files that would be slow to manipulate in order not to affect other ones.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 (and should also work in Windows 11), you can open a new instance of any window by holding down <kbd>shift</kbd> and then clicking the program in your taskbar.

In Excel, this will also work as long as you are not on the start screen.

So try opening excel, click new or open an existing sheet, then hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and click excel in your taskbar. It now should open a second instance of excel in a new window.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Windows 11. The only way I found to do this is by using Run or a terminal (which is ok, but not as convenient as pressing Alt or Shift and clicking on an icon on the taskbar.